# How to troubleshoot Application Popup issues 0XC0000142 and 0XC000009a

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log

I am running randomly into 1 of these popups when our application runs. The machines range from 8GB/8Core to 24GB/24Core and run Windows Server 2008 R2. The application is a bunch of perl scripts and exe's that are expected to utilitize the server well. The process tree can be quite  deep (5-6 child levels) and quite broad (60-70 level 1 processes).

We hit this issues every 1% run on random machines. The application stalls on popup, unless someone clicks the damn button.

The event log reads as cmd.exe -> "Failed to initialize app. Click OK to close app"

How could I reliably repro these issues?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588%28PROT.10%29.aspx), these mean:

**0xc0000142:** {DLL Initialization Failed} Initialization of the dynamic link library $Library failed. The process is terminating abnormally.

**0xc000009a:** Insufficient system resources exist to complete the API.

This tells me that the process was not able to be started. I'm guessing the second error occurs before the first one, just from how they read. What exactly is being exhausted I'm not certain. It could also be a timing issue; all those threads starting and stopping may set things up for an error once in a great while. If you can't repro it by just starting a bunch of stuff until it can't start 'em no more, then it's probably timing and those are devilishly hard to repro.